# AES with linear operations: AES with no s-box?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, aes

I am looking to find an AES algorithm/implementation that is linear. I know that s-box is the only part in the AES method that has non-linear operations. So is there any algorithm/implementation that does not use S-box or any other way to make it linear? I am aware that this would be less secure, but that is okay for this purpose.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. The right forum is crypto.stackexchange.com. That said, if you removed the S-box, it wouldn't be Rijndael any more. It'd be something else, and so not AES. Do you really mean "can I make a cipher that does not require an S-box?" Or do you really mean AES specifically?

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly.. removing the s-box affects the NIST rules? If so, I would like to have a cipher without s-box.

Comment: I don't know why you would call this "NIST rules." AES is a specific algorithm (a specific set of configurations of Rijndael). If you change the algorithm, then it's not AES. But sure, there are plenty of ciphers without an S-Box: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher (that's a joke, please don't use the Caesar Cipher). You should expand your question to the actual problem you're trying to solve (why linear? what security guarantees do you require?) and post it to crypto.stackexchange.com.